# При добавлении в EditText (Android) любого элемента меняется цифровая клавиатура на буквенную

Tags: android, android-edittext

Пытаюсь реализовать отображение тегов при вводе текста с клавиатуры

1. Есть обычный `EditText`, на который подвешен слушатель `TextWatcher`.
2. Аттрибуты:

   ```
   android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textShortMessage"
   android:maxLines="4"
   ```
3. Как только в методе `TextWatcher'a` `afterTextChanged(Editable string)`  вижу, что некое слово содержит шарп (#) - через `ImageSpan` оформляю его в виде тега.
4. Устанавливаю новый текст в `EditText` ->

   ```
   SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(string);
   ImageSpan imageSpan = getImageSpan(string); 
   int startPosition = getStartPosition(string);
   int endPosition = getEndPosition(string);
   spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, startPosition, endPosition,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   setText(spannableString);
   ```

Всё работает хорошо и выглядит вот так:
[image: пример]

**Проблема**: после вызова `setText(spannableString);` цифровая клавиатура (если был ввод цифр) или клавиатура со смайлами (если был ввод смайлов) меняется на обычную текстовую.

Клавиатуры меняются независимо от того, есть ImageSpan или нет. 
(если в методе `afterTextChanged(Editable string)` я вызываю просто `setText(string)` - клавиатура меняется).

Клавиатуры НЕ меняются, если не вызывать `setText(string)`.

**Вопросы:** как добиться того, чтобы клавиатуры не менялись, когда я добавляю `ImageSpan` внутрь `EditText`? Возможно, я вообще иду не по тому пути. Возможно, есть проще и эффективнее решения, о работе с оформлением слов внутри `EditText`?

Буду рад выслушать любые идеи! Спасибо.

Comment: Friends, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, решение по добавлению картинки внутрь EditText и чтобы клавиатура не прыгала было таким:

1. Устанавливаем тег через setText и запоминаем его
2. При следующих вводах смотрим, если тег не менялся - не используем setText. Тогда клавиатуры не переключаются (не вызывается метод завершения ввода) и всё работает корректно.
3. Когда меняется тег, удаляем Spannable и устанавливаем их заново

В примерах ниже вы можете посмотреть как
а) Очищать устаревшие спаны
б) Создавать ImageSpan (в данном случае - делать из текста рисунок)
в) Устанавливать картинку - текст внутрь EditText

Надеюсь, это поможет кому-либо.

> ```
>  /**
>      * Clean the formatting of the string.
>      *
>      * @param editable text which has spannable format
>      */
>     private void removeOldSpans(Editable editable){
>         Object[] spans = editable.getSpans(0, editable.toString().length(), Object.class);
>         for (Object span : spans) {
>             if (span instanceof ImageSpan) {
>                 editable.removeSpan(span);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

```
/**
     * Setting formats to tags.
     *
     * @param startTag a first tag in the string
     * @param endTag a last tag in the string
     * @param editable the string with text
     */
    public void setTagSpans(String startTag, String endTag, Editable editable) {
        oldStartTag = startTag;
        oldEndTag = endTag;

        removeTextChangedListener(tw); //disable listener

        String currentText = editable.toString();

        //remove old span
        removeOldSpans(editable);

        //create new span
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(editable);

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(startTag) && TextUtils.isEmpty(endTag)) {
            //we have only first tag
            final ImageSpan startTagSpan = getChipsSpan(startTag);
            spannableString.setSpan(startTagSpan, 0, startTag.length(),
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(startTag) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(endTag)) {
            //we have only last tag
            final ImageSpan endTagSpan = getChipsSpan(endTag);
            int last = currentText.lastIndexOf("#");
            spannableString.setSpan(endTagSpan, last, currentText.length(),
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        } else if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(startTag) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(endTag)) {
            //we have both tags at the same time
            final ImageSpan startTagSpan = getChipsSpan(startTag);
            final ImageSpan endTagSpan = getChipsSpan(endTag);
            int last = currentText.lastIndexOf("#");
            spannableString.setSpan(startTagSpan, 0, startTag.length(),
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spannableString.setSpan(endTagSpan, last, currentText.length(),
                    Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }

        setText(spannableString, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        forceSetCursorPosition = spannableString.length();
        setSelection(forceSetCursorPosition);

        addTextChangedListener(tw);
    }


/**
     * Format the tag from a text into an image span.
     *
     * @param tag text
     * @return text which has been formatted into an image span
     */
    private ImageSpan getChipsSpan(String tag) {
        //Build chips view
        final TextViewFontExt textViewFontExt = new TextViewFontExt(getContext());
        textViewFontExt.setTypeface(Helper.Fonts.getTypeface(getContext(), "fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf"));
        textViewFontExt.setLayoutParams(
                new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        textViewFontExt.setText(tag);
        textViewFontExt.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chats_chips_span_text_size));
        textViewFontExt.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
        textViewFontExt.setPadding(
                (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chats_chips_span_padding_lr),
                (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chats_chips_span_padding_top),
                (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chats_chips_span_padding_lr),
                (int)getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.chats_chips_span_padding_bottom));

        Drawable tagBackground;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
            tagBackground = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tag_input_background);
        } else {
            tagBackground = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tag_input_background, null);
        }
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            textViewFontExt.setBackgroundDrawable(tagBackground);
        } else {
            textViewFontExt.setBackground(tagBackground);
        }

        //Build chips bitmap
        int spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        textViewFontExt.measure(spec, spec);
        textViewFontExt.layout(0, 0, textViewFontExt.getMeasuredWidth(), textViewFontExt.getMeasuredHeight());

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textViewFontExt.getWidth(), textViewFontExt.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        canvas.translate(-textViewFontExt.getScrollX(), -textViewFontExt.getScrollY());

        textViewFontExt.draw(canvas);
        textViewFontExt.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        Bitmap cacheBitmap = textViewFontExt.getDrawingCache();
        Bitmap tagBitmap = cacheBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tagBitmap);
        bitmapDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), bitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

        //Cleanup
        textViewFontExt.destroyDrawingCache();
        bitmap.recycle();
        cacheBitmap.recycle();

        return new ImageSpan(bitmapDrawable);

    }
```